# How can I solve the 'could not convert string to float:' error when I try to embed sequence data in a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequence, bioinformatics

I want to replace the sequence data with a single character or string and put it into my keras model. Replacing sequence data with a string is done  by including padding as follows.

My Enviornment is Python 3.6.7, Tensorflow 1.12.0, Keras 2.2.4.

Data shape:

```
x input: (23714, 160), y input: (23714, 7)
```

One example sequence:

```
array(['M', 'A', 'S', 'K', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'L', 'A', 'K', 'G',
       'L', 'N', 'G', 'K', 'E', 'V', 'A', 'A', 'Q', 'V', 'K', 'A', 'P',
...
       'L', 'V', 'L', 'K'], dtype='<U1')
```

I tried to use the Embedding layer in keras, but the following error occurred.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'I'
```

The embedding layer is used as follows.

Model:

```
model = Sequential ()
model.add (InputLayer (input_shape = (160,)))
model.add (Embedding (30000, 160))
model.add (LSTM (160, activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense (7, activation = & quot; softmax & quot;))
model.summary ()
model.compile (loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "man", metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.fit (x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 100, validation_split = 0.2)
print (model.evaluate (x_test, y_test) [1])
```

If I change the value of 30000 to another value, only 'I' of error will change to 'M' or other string.

I tried to put it in the Dense layer instead of using the embedding layer in the other way, but the same error occurred.
Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S'
```

Model:

```
model = Sequential ()
model.add (Dense (64, input_shape = (160,), activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense (7, activation = & quot; softmax & quot;))
model.summary ()
model.compile (loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "man", metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.fit (x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 100, validation_split = 0.2)
print (model.evaluate (x_test, y_test) [1])
```

To summarize, an error occurs when trying to insert padded sequence data into an embedding or dense layer. The sequence data was converted to an array and reshape was not performed.

If I do reshape, I get the following error, so I do not reshape first, but I want to solve the embedding problem.
`ValueError: can not reshape array of size 3794240 into shape (23714,1)`

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have this completely wrong...

but the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

may be an indication that you need to have numerical data, not string data.

So, encode the sequence into a numerical format (Digital Signal Processing (DSP))

[This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6448311/) paper highlights a number of methods for doing this...

This table comes from that paper:
[image]